# Where can I find the identifier from an UIController for instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Where can I find the identifier from an UIController (see "xxx" on the code below)?

I tried everything nothing worked, I've been searching nobody mention where to get it... sounds like is something very obvious but I can't figure..

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    BookMenuController* bookControll = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"xxx"];

    bookControll.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:bookControll animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the identifier in your StoryBoard, click on the UIViewController, and under the attribute inspector you should see a field called Identifier. That is your "xxx".

[image: Identifier]

Comment: thanks, Do you know should I put on storyboard name? I figure the issue is there

Comment: As long as your main storyboard is named "MainStoryboard" then it should be okay.

Comment: @esthepiking the storyboards name doesn't matter, the identifier is a reference to a controller within the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You set the identifier in interface builder identity inspector for the controller

Comment: it seems my problem is the storyboard name, I didn't see that on interface builder

Comment: This options seems to be gone on XCode 4.5 How do we set the view controller's identifier?